# Vlookup not working with text search

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hi I am trying to do a vlookup from the sheet name "SES Companies" and then displaying it on the sheet named "Showcase".

I used the formula as shown below in the picture but it always display the stock code above the company I am searching for.

Say I am looking for Action Asia Limited and it should return A59. Instead, it returns SH3W which is the cell (B11) above B12

Shows the sheet "SES Companies"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/onm2gxir29mhioq/p1.jpg?dl=0

Shows the formula I used on the sheet "Showcase"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3hktowk07sdtax/p2.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Looks correct to me. Do you have anymore information about this particular search? What is your search value for `company name`? Perhaps it's ambiguous and `SH3W` is the first hit.

Comment: Say when I search for Abr, it returns the text "A35" when it should return "533"

Comment: That is due to how the approximate match works. It searches from the searches from the top of your range until it comes across a value that is greater than the lookup value and returns the value before that. In this case the full company name is considered greater than "Abr" so it returns the value from the previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula instead. It will return the first match found for the bit of text entered in cell `B1`.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1&"*",'SES Companies'!A2:C1214,2,FALSE)
```

You could alter the formula to look for a piece of text within the Company name and return the first match.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*",'SES Companies'!A2:C1214,2,FALSE)
```

**Note:** do keep in mind it will always return the first found result, so if you have duplicates you need a different search value.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfect! What does the alteration do? Is there anywhere I could read up on this? Thank you!

Comment: @user3758532, the alternate version allows you to enter text and it will search for that text within the name. Example: `Golf` would return `ADQU`. I can't find the exact link anymore, but Google for `VLOOKUP using partial match`

Answer (score 0):

The TRUE argument at the end of your Vlookup means it is looking for an approximate match in your data. If your data is not sorted and/or there is not an exact match to your lookup value, it will return unexpected results. Change your formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,'SES Companies'!A2:C1214,2,FALSE)
```

EDIT after further comments:

Try asking your users to enter a wildcard character eg* if they are using a shortened company name on an approximate search, this should make "Abr*" greater than "Abr Holdings". I would also include a box to show the actual company name returned otherwise it may not be obvious to the users when it has returned details for a different company.

Comment: Hi, I need it to be True because some names are quite long and people will use short names to search for them. Say when I search for Abr instead of the full text "Abr Holdings Limited", it returns the text "A35" when it should return "533". I sorted it according to alphabetical order for the companies' names.